# C - sizeof(string) result is less than it should be

Tags: c, sizeof

I know that a string should be n+1 in length, but for some reason my program is printing the sizeof(string) as n-2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char name [] = "Tom";
    int x = sizeof(name);
    int i;

    printf("sizeof(name) = %d\n", i);

    for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        printf("Character at %d is %c\n", i, name[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: You're printing the value of `i`, which is uninitialized.

Comment: Read your compiler warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're printing `i`, not `x`.
`i` was never initialized, so you get undefined behavior.

Comment: When you use x instead of i, it gives 4, which is the n+1 you were expecting.

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem is that I'm an idiot. Thanks. XD